# read int form a file in java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a *.txt file that it has data like this:

```
  1222 25 36 25 14 25 25 36 363 25 15
    1253 69 54 87 54 285
]±غ'Q­ہx¸'،2ذç12â· 'ئ‰؟¦خ&{3ع*U6هؤ­ر–¨ر،³ڑُ‌ں¢œغ)™پ÷ةtڑت†éYْ(زH5x¸2ش/¨#ژ‏ظœ,tx[Kh6”¨
rٹ±k'¨اqaيïذüـvqشQ­0H888/ ح‎lںR–>Kْ¹bف‘دô†)oŒىٹط.fNؤ8ک„ٌnpwَ§IMقJ™؟س5؛x.Zµ‎™7ˆے¨‌أئ°—لف):©¢چR¢سï¶J±@JœOْ‏5TMè§è9´«7 –دس54)ںشw>’âغ2›Zi@وûr&  طFو-dة ôƒ( œءxƒ§أh(¢ش‘»إV¨پ~ؤF؟!]&´ye\جہ„°?ّ!Uج3ص­wyc†P`¬:
ِS…ةّEژœ Zشâku‍ X§Rٌ¦ص«{â‹YwOڈ48¹Wٌ“i¾َه#™²|(³bˆiتژ-»çJ¯‍صl¦ر“+ءC’µہڈ™،£ظ(2€j¤ًگdك(`اء—ê¯³[f‌
```

first 17 chars of that are integer and others are binary.

now i want to read first 17 chars.
how can i read them?

Comment: Your terminology isn't quite clear. Based on your example file, you should say the file starts with a string of 17 numbers, separated by whitespaces and/or newline characters, terminated by a newline character. Note that the first whitespace already is a single *char*. So, what do you actually mean?

Answer (score 3):

This is something you can do with a [`java.io.Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
File f = new File("yourtxt.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
for (int i = 0; i < 17 && s.hasNextInt(); ++i)
{
    int inputInteger = s.nextInt();
    // Handle your int here...
}
```

---

EDIT: The exception that is thrown is probably because of bytes you don't need between the integers.

Maybe you can try to do something like this:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(yourFile));
String numbers = dis.readLine() + " " + dis.readLine();
numbers = numbers.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
String[] array = numbers.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
{
    int inputInteger = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
    // handle inputInteger here...
}
```

Comment: better add checks for `hasNextInt()`

Comment: I test it but it doesn't work.this code only read first line and then throwed exception

Comment: @mehdi: it's always nice to post the stacktrace if you get an exception.

Comment: Any other way (non Scanner) - any Java 7 way ? This `byte[] readAllBytes = Files.readAllBytes(ROOT_PATH); final Integer rootId = Integer.valueOf(new String(readAllBytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));`fails. I have written it using `Files.write(ROOT_PATH, ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(newRoot)
    .array());`

Answer (score 0):

I check it and it works

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        File f = new File("my.txt");

        if(f.exists()){
            Scanner scanner = null;
            try {
                scanner = new Scanner(f);            
            int [] arrayInt = new int [17];
            int i = 0;
            while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                arrayInt[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
            }

            for(int tailElement : arrayInt){
                System.out.println(tailElement);
            }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }
}
```