# is there a way to read values from a file int an array and initialize those value?

Tags: java, loops, file

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\HIM\\IdeaProjects\\File Tutorial\\src\\quad.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            double a , b, c;
            double[] arr = new double[3];
            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(arr[i]);
                }
            }
            a = arr[0];
            System.out.println(a);
            b = arr[1];
            System.out.println(b);
            c = arr[2];
            System.out.println(c);

        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

i used this code, but from the loop that transferred the values 2, 3, 4, into the array it was read successful but i tried initializing those array values into a,b,c, but it only reads the last value and assign it to a.

Comment: is this an answer for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438360/read-int-form-a-file-in-java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what your input file looks like, so it's hard to tell you *exactly* what's wrong, but I suspect the issue is you are using `hasNextLine` in your loop, but `nextInt` when you read. This won't behave in the way you expect for input like this, for example:

`1 2 3`

Notice that there is one line, so `hasNextLine` will return false because, while there are multiple ints, there is only one line.

What you probably want instead is [Scanner#hasNextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt())

In addition, this logic is probably not correct:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
      System.out.println(arr[i]);
 }
```

When a Scanner moves to the next token, you cannot go back. So you can only read from it once without creating a new scanner.

What you likely want is the following:

```
int i = 0;
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
   arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
   System.out.println(arr[i]);
   i++;
}
```

This will go through the scanner once and correctly populate your values.

Answer (score 0):

```
           for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(arr[i]);
                }
            }
```

Look at the inner loop. You're running `while(scanner.hasNextLiine()` however i is never getting iterated while you read the file. As a result, you read the entire file, but always put it into `arr[i=0]`.

A better solution may be

```
int i = 0;
while(scanner.hasNextLine() && i < arr.length){
    arr[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Which will combine the functionality of your while and for loop. Another alternative:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length && scanner.hasNextLine(); i++){
    arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Chris's answer is also valid. `nextInt` and `hasNextLine` aren't the same thing. But in this case I'm assuming your file has ints on every line.

Comment: Caught the loop on review, so you beat me to it :-)